# Is it better to rotate an arrow-icon or to use separate icons for right and left arrow?

Tags: android, icons

In Android, i have an Arrow-Right icon (SVG). I also need an Arrow-Left icon. Is it better to use Arrow-Right and rotate it by 180° or use a separate drawable?

I imagine that rotating one icon is more efficient than loading a second drawable, but what if i have to use the icon hundreds of times in my activity?

Also, what if i have to use a bigger image (a .png file > 1MB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing, if it's really an icon, it'll be small.  So small that I probably would just add the rotated version.  If you were to rotate it programmatically, you could cache it, of course.  If you were worried about the size of your app, you could rotate the image and save it into the app's disk cache so that you don't have to do each time.  At least I'd avoid having to rotate the image hundreds of times in the activity (or app).

Comment: For something as small as an icon I would probably rotate it once when loading the program and save it in memory - The rotate would probably be as quick or quicker than reading from storage

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering, ill probably just use two drawables and leave the rotation. Ive already been asked "why there is only arrow-right"?
I dont think the saving to storage method is needed at the moment, but ill keep it in mind for bigger/multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

If you need icons for the menu or the action bar there is no place to rotate it, you just assign a drawable resource ID to the menu item.

The standard (correct) way is to generate PNG's for each screen density and in your case for each orientation.

http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Comment: Unfortunately I need the icons inside the layout. Im programming a clothing game where the user can select different clothes by pressing arrows on the left and the right side of the screen. Thank you for answering though, the link looks interesting.